# Proguard - Keep all classes and methods names, but obfuscated Fields

Tags: java, proguard, obfuscation

I trying to keep all classes and methods names, but obfuscated all the fields in my project.

For example, this code:

```
public class MyClass {
    private int    myInt;
    public String  myString;

    void myMethod() {
        // Method code;
    }
}
```

Should turn into this code

```
public class MyClass {
    private int    a1;
    public String  a2;

    void myMethod() {
        // Obfuscated method code;
    }
}
```

Note that the class name and method name doesn't get obfuscated, but the field name does.

I'm guessing it is some sort of combination with `keepnames` and `keepclassmembernames`, but I'm not sure what is the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

Try below if you can add access modifier to the method you want to keep , e.g you want to keep all public methods.

```
-keep class MyClass
-keepclassmembers class MyClass  {
    public <methods>;  
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work